# Just installed Confluent Cloud CLI but getting a Java version warning

Tags: command-line, java

I just installed the Confluent Cloud CLI and Java on MacOS but I am getting a warning every time I run a ccloud command:

```
Warning: Could not determine  Java version
```

I installed the Confluent CLI based on [this](https://docs.confluent.io/current/cloud/cli/install.html#ccloud-install-cli). And java via:

```
brew cask install java
```

I've run a check to make sure Java is installed ("...$ java -version") and return the following:

```
openjdk version "11.0.1" 2018-10-16
OpenJDK Runtime Environment 18.9 (build 11.0.1+13)
OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM 18.9 (build 11.0.1+13, mixed mode)
```

Answer (score 0):

Can you share your install command and how you're running `ccloud`?

Can you also check your path? `which ccloud && ccloud --version`.

That error message is from the much older java-based version of `ccloud`, afaict. I want to make sure you're calling the version of `ccloud` you just installed.

The `ccloud` CLI shouldn't have any java dependency (but the `confluent` CLI does, for running Confluent Platform locally for testing purposes).